# Find an image in a canvas by coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg

**Edit:**

1) basically I would like to know if there is a way to know if in an html canvas there is an image in a given point.

```
var point = [5, 8]
```

there is an image on that point? there is a command for find out?

2) the canvas is an hex map so the images are on regular positions in the grid. They can't be halfway. So a generic `point` can be brought back to the insertion point for the image and the question become: there is a (fast) way to know if in an html canvas there is an image with a given insertion point?

3) can help if I'm using Raphael?

4) I have a working solution: to confront the (x, y) attributes (insertion point) of ALL the images with the coordinates of `point`, but it's very slow. I'm looking for something faster. If you are interessed in my solution, read below. Comment and improvement on my solution are welcome but my question is different: I'm looking for a different solution and specifically I'm looking for the answers to my questions above.

**/edit**

I have an hex map and I want to find which images are in an exe given the exe coordinates.

My code is working but I hope for something more efficient.

To be precise when i click on an exe I want to know if in the six border exes there is a specific image. Read the comment in the code

My `javascript`:

```
var paper_map = Raphael(canvas_map, '100%', '100%');

var Image = paper_map.image(path_image, x-16, y-14, width, high);
[...]

var border_list=find_border_list(col, row)
//find_border_list function gives a list of coordinates for the 6 border exes [[c1, r1], ... [c6, r6]]
var my_exe_list=[];
for (var i=0; i<border_list.length; i++ ) {
    var coord = number_to_coord(border_list[i][0], border_list[i][1]); 
    //number_to_coord function transforms coordinates (column, row) in (x,y)
    var x = coord[0]-16; //I find the coordinates of the 'corner' of the exe
    var y = coord[1]-14;
    //each image is drawed starting from a 'corner' of an exe
    var child_list=canvas_map.lastElementChild.childNodes;
    //here's my problem: this list is huge because it contains all the images of the canvas!!
    for (var j=2; j<child_list.length; j++){
        if (child_list[j].tagName == 'image') {
            if (child_list[j].attributes.x.value==x && 
                child_list[j].attributes.y.value==y && 
                child_list[j].href.baseVal.slice(child_list[j].href.baseVal.lastIndexOf('/')+1).startsWith('mystring')) {
                    //the first two conditions find all the images on my exe, the third find which I'm interessed in (based on the name)
                    my_exe_list.push(child_list[j])
            };
        };
    };
};
```

My `html`:

```
<div id='canvas_map' class='canvas can_map' style='position:absolute; left:133px; top:0px;'></div>
```

`console.log(canvas_map)` = `<div id="canvas_map" class="canvas can_map" style="position: absolute; left: 133px; top: 0px; height: 520px; width: 1371px;">`

`console.log(child_list)` = `NodeList [ <desc>, <defs>, <image>, <image>, <image> ... ]`

`console.log(child_list[j])` = `<image x="53" y="56" width="33" height="27" preserveAspectRatio="none" href="/my/path/image_name.png">`

So the problem is I cycle six times in a very long list (could be some thousands of images):

```
var child_list=canvas_map.lastElementChild.childNodes;
```

Just to know I draw the images with [Raphael](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) and I can use jquery.

Comment: Canvas in context of the tag you added to the question is a specific type of element (namely a HTML5 canvas element)  I don't see any use of the canvas in your code apart from a collection named `canvas_map`. Raphael uses SVG so you will get an answer sooner if you change the question's tag canvas to one or more of  SVG, Raphael, HTML, DOM

Comment: @Blindman67 added info to my post. My solution don't use canvas but maybe a faster solution is -if possible- to read (in the canvas) the images under the coordinates assigned. Something like a click (event.target) but without click. I'm not sure if Raphael or DOM can help, HTML is too generic. I have inserted SVG but the images are .png

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]